# NumericUpDown to percentage then to hex

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, hex, percentage, numericupdown

I have a numericupdown control on my form. The value is 17, I need to store that number into a variable, then convert it to a percentage of 0-255, then convert it to hex.

What I have: 17
Where I need to get: ((17 / 100) * 256 ) - 1 = 42.52 which gets rounded to 43
Then I need to convert that to hex: 43 = 2B

What I don't know/understand.

When I take in the value, what type of variable do I store it in ? string ? Int? double ?

Can someone provide an example please.

Thank you,
James

Comment: Why do you think a string? Why do you think an int? Why do you think a double? What advantages does each bring? What disadvantages based on what you want to do with the value?

Comment: Check the signature in msdn: `NumericUpDown.Value` is of type `decimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go this way:

```
decimal value = 17m; // or YourNumericUpDownControl.Value
int percent = (int)Math.Round(((value / 100) * 256) - 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
string hex = percent.ToString("X");
```

`NumericUpDown.Value` is of type `decimal` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so you should start with a `decimal`. I've entered 17 here directly, as you did in your example.

Comment: Very nice and clean, I knew it had to be simple and I was just over thinking the whole situation. Thank you.